# Magento 2: How to get shipment collection on phtml?

Tags: magento-2.1, collection, model, sales, shipment

I'm trying to get the shippment collection on `popup.pthml`, but not able to get.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$shipmentCollection = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\Collection'); 
$shipmentCollection->loadByIncrementId($shipId);
echo "<pre>";print_r($shipmentCollection->getData());die;
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont use Object Manager. 
using DI and inject the `Magento\Sales\Model\Order` and get the value.

```
 protected $order;
```

in construct add this

```
 public function __construct(     
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order

    ) {
        $this->order = $order;
    }
```

You can use this like

```
$resultShippment = $this->order->loadByIncrementId($shipId);
```

Comment: can you please suggest how can do

Comment: sure i will provide the code

Comment: If it is not work please let me know. else please change to resolve. it will helpful for others.