# How to get shipment id in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, shipment

I have created a custom module for order tracking.

Now when the order is completed the shipment id is generated.

So, How to get the shipment id?

I have my block like this :

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Codazon. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Codazon\AjaxCartPro\Block;
class Trackorder extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    protected $orderRepository;
    protected $_coreRegistry;

    public function __construct(      
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []      
    )
    {    

         $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
         $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;   
         parent::__construct($context, $data);   
    }

    public function getOrderStatus()
    {

        $orderId = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('order_id');
        $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
        $state = $order->getState(); // Print Order State(Complete, Processing, ....)
        return $state;
    }   

    public function getShipmentID()
    {
        $orderId = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('order_id');
        $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
        $shipment = $order->getShipmentsCollection();
        return $shipment;
    }
}
```

But `getShipmentID()` this function does not work for me.
How to resolve this problem?

How to get shipment id If order is completed.

Answer (score 2):

STEP-BY-STEP PROCESS TO GET SHIPMENT TRACKING INFORMATION PROGRAMMATICALLY IN MAGENTO 2
Please follow the below steps to learn how to get shipment tracking information in Magento 2.

STEP – 1
First of all, create an event.xml file in the app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\ folder and paste the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_shipment_save_after">
          <observer name="track_shipment" instance="Vendor\Extension\Observer\Shipment" />
     </event>
</config>
```

STEP – 2
Next, open the Shipment.php file from the app\code\Vendor\Extension\Observer\ folder and paste the following code.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class Shipment implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        try {
            $shipment = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment();
            $tracksCollection = $shipment->getTracksCollection();
            foreach ($tracksCollection->getItems() as $track) {
                $track_number = $track->getTrackNumber();
                $carrier_name = $track->getTitle();
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
        }
    }
}
?>
```

And it’s done!

Answer (score 0):

The class is in Magento\Sales\Model\Order. Please check the 
[Shippment collection](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178076/magento-2-how-to-get-shipment-collection-on-phtml/178084#178084). Hope it will helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

Your **getShipmentID()** method need some modification.

Try following way:

```
public function getShipmentID()
{
    $orderId = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('order_id');
    $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
    $shipmentCollection = $order->getShipmentsCollection();
    $shipmentId = 0;
    foreach ($shipmentCollection as $shipment) {
        $shipmentId = $shipment->getId();
    }
    return $shipmentId;
}
```

If order has multiple shipment then try following way:

```
public function getShipmentID()
{
    $orderId = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('order_id');
    $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
    $shipmentCollection = $order->getShipmentsCollection();
    $shipmentId = [];
    foreach ($shipmentCollection as $shipment) {
        $shipmentId[] = $shipment->getId();
    }
    return $shipmentId;
}
```

Comment: hi @Sohel, I have used event "sales_order_shipment_save_after" and in the observer tried this $shipment = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment();
   $shipmentId = $shipment->getId();, shipmentid not returning

Answer (score 0):

if anyone needs to use in objmanager try this.

```
    $order_id = 140;
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
    $shipmentCollection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface');
    $orderRepository = $shipmentCollection->get($order_id);
    $shipmenttotal = $orderRepository->getShipmentsCollection();
    foreach ($shipmenttotal as $shipment) {
        $shipmentId = $shipment->getId();
    }
    print_r($shipmentId);
```